# While removing atom following error are shown

Tags: apt, package-management, sublime-text

I tried to uninstall atom from ubuntu 16.04 using

```
sudo apt remove atom || sudo apt remove --purge atom
```

command and following are the errors, please help me in resolving the issue.

```
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list (Suite)    
E: The list of sources could not be read.    
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list (Suite)    
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

While running the following command

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list
```

this was the output: deb https://download.sublimetext.com/apt/dev/

[output for cat command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLdgy.png)

Comment: Let's see what's in here `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list` with `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list` add to your question!

Comment: Done. Please check the question now @george

Comment: Please post the output into your question!

Comment: I have gone with the similar solution but still the problem is not resolved, I am trying to remove atom and i am getting this errors, also while installing sublime I am getting these errors

Comment: @George Please check the question iI have attached an screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open that file using `nano` text editor and add a space like so:

1. sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list

   ```
   deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/dev/
   ```

Then run `sudo apt update`, and try again.

Comment: E: The package libisccfg140 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
It is now showing me this error and a warning when I run `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3` error is **/etc/apt/sources.list/** @george

Comment: Please post another question for the installation of atom.